# How do I detect the options passed to the documentclass from my own style?

Tags: packages, package-writing, options

In the `listings` package, they note that "a global `\documentclass`-option `draft` is recognized, so you don’t need to repeat it as a package option"

I tried looking into its source to see how it accomplishes this, but I wasn't able to find the magic bit.  How does one detect the global `\documentclass` options from within an independent style/package?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is done automatically for all packages by LaTeX's `\ProcessOptions`.
It checks if any of the global class options are defined by the package and executes the ones which are. 
You do not need to do anything special in your package.

This is explained in [clsguide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide), page 18. The source code which implements it can be seen in [source2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e), page 370.

Answer (score 6):

I think the story is more subtle than Martin has had the time to explain. It is the starred form of `\ProcessOptions,` when issued in packages, that copies and processes global options (submitted via `\documentclass`) in the order in which they were submitted via `\documentclass.` The unstarred variant of `\ProcessOptions` doesn’t copy global options from `\documentclass` (except when issued in a class file – where, in the LaTeX2e kernel approach, `\@curroptions` come from `\@classoptionslist`) and processes the options in the order in which they were declared.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for explaining it further. I didn't do it in that detail on purpose, but pointed him to the `clsguide` where this details are explained. IMO he has to read that document anyway.